# how to upload a csv file to mysql database using php

Tags: php, html, wampserver

I have created a website which requires me to upload a csv file into the mysql database (Wamp server). Since I have never done this before a detailed answer with steps will be really helpful. I need the user to upload file using html input file option and then a php code to upload this file to mysql database. Iam using this code

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","","");
mysql_select_db("sg",$con);
define('CSV_PATH','C:/Users/mkutbudd/Desktop/');
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "dum.csv";
if (($getfile = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) { 
        $data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",");
        while (($data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
         $num = count($data); 
         for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
             $result = $data; 
             $str = implode(",", $result); 
             $slice = explode(",", $str);
             $col1 = $slice[0]; 
             $col2 = $slice[1];
             $col3 = $slice[2]; 
$query = "INSERT INTO dummy(dum1,dum2,dum3)
VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."')";
$s=mysql_query($query, $con ); 
     }
   } 
  }
echo "File data successfully imported to database!!"; 
mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Your first step is to allow user to upload a file, and then you need to handle the errors if there are, validate the file, and if everything is correct, then move the uploaded file to its place: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php
- Then you need to parse your file, with a php function for it: http://hu1.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php
- After this, you need to create a connection to the database: http://hu1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- And then you need to insert your data into your table with a loop, like foreach on your array, what you created from fgetcsv: http://hu1.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

There are an alternative way, if you have right to run `system` or `execute` functions and you have right to run mysql command, then you can use the `mysql load data` command: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Done.